# ListView builder inside a ListView Builder

Tags: listview, flutter

I am trying to Dynamically create infinite rows using Listview builder. And inside each row i need to add infinite number of textFields. Why does the nested Listview builder not work?

I tried using Row and then add containers and it works. Why doesnt Listview builder work?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main()
{
  runApp(MainScreen());
}

class MainScreen extends StatefulWidget
{
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {

    return _MainScreenState();
  }
}

class _MainScreenState extends State<MainScreen>{

  int number = 1;
  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
  }


  @override
  Widget build (BuildContext ctxt) {

    var fieldslist = <Widget>[];

    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      fieldslist.add(

          new Container(

              width: 100,
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(4),
              child:TextField(
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.number
              )
          )
      );
    }

    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(title: new Text("Scores Screen"),),
        body: new Column(
          children: <Widget>[

            new Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                new RaisedButton(
                    child: new Text("Add Scores"),
                    onPressed: (){

                      number++;
                      this.setState(()=>{});


                    })
              ],
            ),
            new Expanded(
                child: new ListView.builder
                  (
                    itemCount: number,
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext ctxt, int index) {

                          new Expanded(

                              child: new ListView.builder(

                                  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,

                                  itemCount: 7,
                                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext ctxt, int index){

                                    return new Container(

                                        width: 100,
                                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(4),
                                    child:TextField(
                                            keyboardType: TextInputType.number
                                        )
                                    );


                                  }
                              )

                          );

                    }
                )
            )
          ],
        )
      )
    );
  }


}
```

The screen is blank and nothing happens when i click the button.

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood correctly, you want an horizontal scrollable list inside of your vertival listview ?

If yes, did you try something like this for you horizontal list :

```
Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          SizedBox(
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.85,
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              child: Row(children: _yourList),
            ),
          )
        ],
      )
```

Comment: Yes that is exactly what i want. I tried to integrate your code but that does not help either. Nothing happens when i click the button. I am Able to add the functionality i want something like this. ``` new Row(children : <List Widget with textfields already added>)```. But I am not able to scroll and its giving me error on the UI screen.

Comment: Well, if you want your number to update on press, you can put your 'number++' inside yout setState method. (welcome to stackoverflow, I just saw)

Comment: and concerning the scroll issue, you have to play with these widgets. Maybe you can put my code as child in a card ? (I can't try it now)

Comment: Just figured it out. Wrapped the Row with the Widget List in the SingleChildScrollView and it works. Thanks a lot, Nicole and i am excited to be a part of this community now :)